Browser's back button disabled after navigating multiple pages in flutter web using GetX
I'm building a Flutter web app using GetX for state management and routing, and I'm encountering an issue with browser back navigation. When I navigate multiple levels deep (e.g., from the root page to 4-5 pages down), the browser's back button sometimes skips intermediate pages, and not all pages appear in the browser history stack.
Details of the Problem:
For example, I have the following pages:

HomePage (/)
StoreScreen (/store)
PetDetailScreen (/petDetail/:id)
EditPostScreen (/editPost/:id)

    GetMaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      getPages: [
        GetPage(name: '/', page: () => HomePage()),
        GetPage(name: '/store', page: () => StoreScreen()),
        GetPage(name: '/PetDetailScreen/:docId', page: () => PetDetailScreen(docId: Get.parameters['docId']!)),
        GetPage(name: '/EditPostScreen/:docId', page: () => EditPostScreen( docId: Get.parameters['docId']!)),
      ],
    );

In my app, I navigate between pages using Get.toNamed() to ensure each navigation has a unique URL and creates a new entry in the browser history. For example:
// Navigating to the pet detail page sample navigate 
Get.toNamed('/petDetail/${pet.docId}');

To handle back navigation from the EditPostScreen to the PetDetailScreen, I use WillPopScope:

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          Get.offNamed('/petDetail/${widget.docId}');
          return false;
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          // Page content here...
        ),
      );
    }


Problem:
When I navigate from the HomePage to the StoreScreen, then from the StoreScreen to the PetDetailScreen, and finally from the PetDetailScreen to the EditPostScreen, I expect to be able to use the browser's back button to go back through each page in reverse order. However, after navigating back from the EditPostScreen to the PetDetailScreen, the browser back button becomes disabled and cannot be clicked.
How can I resolve this issue to ensure that each page is consistently accessible in the browser's back history?

try to use Get.back() instead of Get.offNamed(page)

It didn't work. I mean, after going back once, the browser's back button is automatically disabled. That's the issue.

don't use Get.off it gets you off the navigation tree thats why the browser back navigation button is disabled remove all Get.Off replace them  with Get.Back and try again.
